# is it possible for awk to add number of output lines into same output file with filter?

Tags: awk, scripting

I have infile

```
11111
444
989
5512
121318
```

so I'm thinkin to layout an awk command that results in outfile with something like this: `outfile has ${thesemany} matches`

in this case `outfile` will look like:

```
outfile has 2 matches
11111
121318
```

I suppose I must try an `END` block, but this line is supposed to be at the beginning. so got confused between `BEGIN` & `END` block, and where to insert increment operator.

my incomplete `awk-one-liner`

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "outfile has ${thesemany} matches"} {(length($1) >= 5) print $1}' infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save all matching fields to a temporary array and dump an
array in END rule:

```
awk 'length($1) >= 5 {a[$1]; count++; } END {print "outfile has", count, "matches"; for (elem in a) {print elem}}' infile
```

Comment: @Quasímodo: good point

Comment: Change `print "outfile has", count, "matches"` to `print "outfile has", count+0, "matches"` or `printf "outfile has %d matches\n", count` so you get numeric output when there are no matches.

Answer (score 4):

Given that you can't know the number of matches until the `END`, if you want to print the matches themselves after that, then you will need to save those until the `END` as well<sup>1</sup>, ex.:

```
awk '
  length($1) >= 5 {matches = matches (matches ? ORS : "") $1; count++} 
  END {print "outfile has " count+0 " matches"; if(count) print matches}
' infile
```

If you don't care about the output order (or intend to sort the matches anyway) then you could save them in an array instead of a concatenated string.

---

<sup>1</sup> I guess you could buffer the matches externally, something like `awk 'length($1) >= 5 {count++; print $1 | "cat"} END {print "outfile has " count+0 " matches"; close("cat")}' infile`

Comment: your code is convincing,  but it's printing $0 at the end. But if you look at my Q, I'm supposed to print specific column, in sample it is $1 but can be any column as per infile

Comment: much better, but another issue, if I want to print that column twice somewhere, it prints just 1 time only.. like `print matches, "1111", matches` in last part.

Comment: @Sollosa if you have additional requirements, please edit your question